# Knowing from the main view controller when the presented modal view controller is dismissed?

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I wanted to know if its possible to know from the view controller when its presented modal view controller is dismissed ? (i.e. when its view returns?)

I tried:

```
viewWillAppear
viewDidAppear
```

But, these didnt seem to work :(

Can anyone kindly suggest ? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear do work for me - make sure you are not getting false results due to coding errors.

Comment: @Till - do you mean the caller's viewWill-DidAppear is called?

Comment: @Till : they do when u put another vc in the anv controller stack. what about presenting a modal vc ? for me, it doesnt :(

Comment: @Rayfleck yes, once the modal viewController is dismissed, the presenting viewController gets those viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear callbacks (again).

Comment: @Till - this had never worked for me before, so I've been coding around it for like 2 years.  Maybe I wasn't calling super.  I don't know.  Thanks for setting me straight on this.  I'll remove my answer.

Comment: You can try to define a delegate in presented view controller. and the presenting view controller conforms the delegate. when the presented one is dismissed, you call the delegate method in the presenting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a callback solution which takes less modifications to your modal and parent:

In the Model's .h add:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^dismissed)();
```

In the Model's .m put this in the completion when you dismiss the modal:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    if(self.dismissed)
        self.dismissed();
}];
```

In the parent view controller when you instantiate your modal set the dismissed callback:

```
Modal = //Init your modal
[Modal setDismissed:^{
    //do stuff you wanted when it's dismissed
}];
[self presentViewController:Modal animated:YES completion:nil];
```